# Closed form of solution of recurrence equation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exists a closed form of solution of the following recurrence equation: 
$$a_{n+1} =a_n^2 -a_n +1$$

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that say $a_1 = 0$, or do you want a more general solution?

Comment: Note that $a_n^2-a_n+1=(a_n-\frac12)^2+\frac34$, hence with $b_n:=a_n-\frac12$ we have $b_{n+1}=b_n^2+\frac14$. This iteration corresponds to the cusp of the Mandelbrot set.
If $b_0=\frac12$, the sequence is constant; if $|b_0|<\frac12$ the sequence will converge to $\frac12$; if $b_0>\frac12$ it will diverge. So much for the behaviour as $n\to \infty$. Do you really want $b_n$ (or $a_n$) explicitly?

Comment: Also, are you familiar with generating functions?

Comment: See  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html. Your sequence, with $z_1=2$, is Sylvester's sequence, and the $n$th term is the integer closest to $d^{2^n}$, with $d\approx 1.26408$.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing closed form. Write $a_n = x_n + \frac{1}{2}.$ The shifted sequence is
$$ x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + \frac{1}{4}.  $$
As someone mentioned in comments, this gives
$$  x_n \approx \theta^{\left( 2^n \right)}, $$ 
but the bad news is that we can only estimate $\theta$ by calculating elements of the original sequence.

The two related sequences that can be done in closed form are
$$   y_{n+1} = y_n^2  $$ and
$$   z_{n+1} = z_n^2 - 2.  $$ In the latter, when $z_0 > 2,$ take $$ A+B = z_0, \; \; A B = 1,$$ then
$$ z_n = A^{\left( 2^n \right)} + B^{\left( 2^n \right)}  $$